# How to list the stack frame of functions from a dll at runtime

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

**Context:** A Win32/64 Process running  on Win7. I do not build the Process itself, I development a set of dll's "under" it. 
One of the these dll's load third party dlls(plug-ins) which I do not control, but for which I cant get acces to the src.

**Question:** how do I get to list the local variable values at Process runtime from the functions from these plug-in dlls? 
*Remember, I'm sort of în the middle of The call stack Being loaded by the process and loading în turn the dll for which I need to get this info.*
WINdbg maybe, some Minidump functionality API I can call?

*Later Edit:* I have the *. pdbs of the dlls I'm trying to get the local variables from.

Comment: Do you have debugging symbols for the DLLs you want to inspect?  If not, I don't think you can get the variable names at all.

Comment: This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). What are you really trying to accomplish? Why do you need to know the values of local variables outside of your own code?

Comment: If you have access to the source code you can build the dlls.

Comment: @ John: Yes, i have the pdbs of the dlls I want to extract the local variables and Param values from.

Comment: @Remy: I'm trying, as I've stated, to get the values of Local variables from functions and function parameters from another dll I'm loading. The goal is that one of our customer wants some insights on these variables and we will not/cannot provide the code. We have other measures for exporting Interfaces of the functional blocks , but these do not apply here.

Comment: @user3202616 you explained WHAT you are trying to do, but not WHY you need to do it. What is your customer planning on doing with the values? Why does the customer even care what the values are? They are private to the DLL's internal implementation, so they are not easily accessible by outside code. Unless you are prepared to implement a custom mini-debugger,  don't expect to solve this.

Comment: @ Remy: Thanks for the details. Yes, I would not expect that this is easy. It's a requirement. That;s why I've said that I could maybe re-use some of the WinDbg funcitonality or some Crash reporter functionality ( without the crash of course). And yes, the customer probably wants that he does not only see the outcome of the Interfaces, but also the details.